# Target Parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched stackoverflow for the solution and the reason my question is new (I think) is because of the HTML layout am using.

Ques - In the Amazon like menu ([related post](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown)) that I implemented on our site I am not able to retain hover on Parent li when mouse goes into its related Child li.

Now this could be easy if I'd have used child inside parent layout (I believe), but the html layout (that am bound to use) we have, is different where parents element are in one ul and childs in other.

I have created a jsfiddle ([LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/97yD9/3/)) of the issue, and in the JS section you'll find the 'custom' function that interacts with menu transition at way bottom.

Thanks for all the help that you can provide!

jQuery code -

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#main_nav').show();

    $('#clickmenu').hover(function(){
        $('#main_nav').show();
    });

    $('#main_nav').hover(function(){
        $('#main_nav').show();
    }, function(){
        $('#flyouts').hide();
    });

    $('#main_nav li').hover(function(){
        $('#flyouts').show();
        $(this).addClass('hovering');
    }, function(){
        if($('#flyouts').is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).removeClass('hovering');
        }
    });

    $('#flyouts').hover(function(){
        $('#main_nav').show();
        $('#flyouts').show();
    }, function(){
        $('#flyouts').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: So what's the question?, in that fiddle i can't find any hover effect at all.. am i missing something?

Comment: looks like you want to change the layout so that all the root LIs should contain the submenus instead of being separate from them. I think to create such a menu, we just need pure CSS without any jQuery code.

Comment: @TJ When you hover to parent li, child appears. Now when you move into (mouse enter) child area, we need to set background on it's parent li.

Comment: @KingKing No, the layout is not what I mean to change.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help and sorted this (I believe). Check line 156 and 162 of the fiddle.

Edit:
and line 183-187 as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/97yD9/18/

code -

```
jQuery(function($){

    $("#main_nav").menuAim({
        activate: function(a){
            var idx = $(a).index();
            $('#flyouts ul').eq(idx).show();
            $(a).css('border', '3px solid black');
            console.log(a);
        }, 
        deactivate: function(a){
            var idx = $(a).index();
            $('#flyouts ul').eq(idx).hide();
            $(a).css('border', 'none');

        }
    });
```

Comment: only issue is when you move your mouse completely out still on one of the li border black present

Comment: Yes, I am struggling with that only.

Comment: Read "Use Like So:" section on github of the algo, and trying something to get rid of that. Link - https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim